# Threads explained - different answer every time im running code

Tags: java, multithreading

Can someone tell me why these threads doesn't give 1.000.000? And why is the answer different every time im running the code?

I'm trying to create 10 threads, where each of them runs 100.000 times. Therefor i have made a loop, to loop through every thread. It should increment the static x + 1 each time.

```
public class CAOS_thread_demo_5 extends Thread
    {
        public static int x = 0;
    
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        CAOS_thread_demo_5 humhum1 = new CAOS_thread_demo_5();
        CAOS_thread_demo_5 humhum2 = new CAOS_thread_demo_5();
        CAOS_thread_demo_5 humhum3 = new CAOS_thread_demo_5();
        CAOS_thread_demo_5 humhum4 = new CAOS_thread_demo_5();
        CAOS_thread_demo_5 humhum5 = new CAOS_thread_demo_5();
        CAOS_thread_demo_5 humhum6 = new CAOS_thread_demo_5();
        CAOS_thread_demo_5 humhum7 = new CAOS_thread_demo_5();
        CAOS_thread_demo_5 humhum8 = new CAOS_thread_demo_5();
        CAOS_thread_demo_5 humhum9 = new CAOS_thread_demo_5();
        CAOS_thread_demo_5 humhum10 = new CAOS_thread_demo_5();


        humhum1.start();
        humhum2.start();
        humhum3.start();
        humhum4.start();
        humhum5.start();
        humhum6.start();
        humhum7.start();
        humhum8.start();
        humhum9.start();
        humhum10.start();
        try
        {
            humhum1.join();
            humhum2.join();
            humhum3.join();
            humhum4.join();
            humhum5.join();
            humhum6.join();
            humhum7.join();
            humhum8.join();
            humhum9.join();
            humhum10.join();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("*** the end ***");
        System.out.println("#### counter: " + x);
    }
    

    public void run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) `x++` isn't atomic; 2) you don't guarantee visibility of previous updates to `x`. Either surround the `x++` with a synchronized block, or use `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: Because variable `x` is not thread-safe, so you're experiencing [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#In_software), which by their very nature is unpredictable.

Comment: Because `x` is not `volatile`. There are other solutions, but this is the simplest.

Comment: @user207421 ... except that making it `volatile` doesn't solve the problem - the problem will remain exactly the same

Comment: Point of style: Instead of having ten local variables, one for each thread, you could have an array of threads or a list of threads, and then you could loop over the members to create and `start()` each one, and loop over them again to `join()` each one.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, `x++` isn't atomic: it's a read, then a write of the incremented value. Other threads can interleave between these actions.

Secondly, you don't guarantee visibility of previous updates to `x`: you aren't guaranteed to see the updates written by other threads, so a thread might just stomp over the values written by other threads. You can fix this by making `x` `volatile`, but that doesn't fix the atomicity issue.

Either surround the `x++` with a synchronized block (with a common monitor, e.g. `CAOS_thread_demo_5.class`); or use `AtomicInteger`, which guarantees visibility, and provides atomic increment methods (`getAndIncrement()`, `incrementAndGet()`).